# How to download amazon s3 file(audio/video) in angularjs and codeigniter?

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have amazon S3 link like,

**http://mytest.s3.amazonaws.com/audio/3/1431428586_z3PtL.mp3**

I want to downaload this mp3 file.
I tried a lot, but failed!

So Please help!

Comment: And WHAT have you tried so far?

Comment: first make your object public in `s3` bucket than you will be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

In order force download a file in an S3 bucket, you will need to set a Request Header. The specific request header to set is **Content-Disposition: attachment**.

You can set the header when you upload the file via the AWS REST API. As described in the [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html#RESTObjectPUT-requests-request-headers).

Or, you can set it manually in the file properties metadata in the AWS Console [view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfJYx.png).